# Laravel pluck with custom method from model

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel `5.6`. I have a `users` table and `firstname` and `lastname` fields.

In my `User` model I also have this function

```
public function name()
{
    return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
}
```

And now in another controller, I want to create a dropdown menu with all the users. But I would like to display the `name()` and not only the first/lastname.

I'm currently using this

```
$users = \App\User::pluck('lastname', 'id');
return view('myview', compact('MY_collection' , 'users'));
```

And in my view (with [collective/html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html))

```
{!! Form::select('user', $users, isset($user) ? $MY_collection->user: null,  ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Is is possible to use pluck with a method function ? Or should I do something else?

I am also aware of the [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) solution but I don't have a `name` attribute in the database, so it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessors can be any name you choose, they just have to start with `get` and end with `Attribute`:

```
public function getNameAttribute() {
    return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
}

$user->name

// this will give the result as above
public function getBlahBlahBlahAttribute() {
    return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
}

$user->blah_blah_blah
```

Either of these should work with pluck.

```
User::get()->pluck('name');

$user->setAppends(['name']);
$user->pluck('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from declaring the accessor name starting with "**get**" and ending with **Attribute**(*camelCase)* :*getFullNameAttribute*===*full_name* in pluck.

You should add the Accessor  to **$appends** :

```
protected $appends=['<your Accessor name>']
//protected $appends=['full_name']
//usage:
//$this->full_name
```

the **$appends** array gets accessors to append to the model's array form.

then use it:

```
collect(json_decode($modelName->tojson(),true))->pluck('full_name','id')
```

Comment: With your tips, it is indeed working for `$user->tojson()` by example. But the `$user->pluck('name') ` still return me `Column not found`

Comment: try this aproach: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-contact-first-name-and-last-name-in-pluck-method-using-the-relationship

Comment: collect(json_decode($user->tojson(),true))->pluck('full_name','id')

Answer (score 1):

You can concate the first name and last name like this.

```
$user = App\User::select(DB::raw('CONCAT(firstname, ", ", lastname) AS full_name'),'id')->pluck('full_name','id');
```